# How can I rename programs shortcuts in Windows 10 menu?

Tags: windows-10-preview

I'm trying the latest Windows 10.

I installed Office 2007, to see how it works.

The problem is the shortcuts are named all like "Microsoft Office Word 2007", "Microsoft Office Excel 2007" and if I add the tile to the menu it gets shortened to "Microsoft Office", for EVERY program.

So I went to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office`, I renamed the shortcuts, but still it does not show the updated file name. Rebooted countless times, still can't get the new file name.

Then I added a new shortcut in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, but still does not show.

Do I need to run some command to reindex the start menu?

I tried to restart explorer.exe but still my custom shortcuts aren't showing...

Comment: There is a good chance what you describe is actually a bug.  If you create a new user do the shortcuts appear?

Comment: I'm downloading and installing the latest build to see if this has been fixed, or not

Comment: The edited shortcut is shown after upgrading to build 10074, but it's not possible to create a new one.

Comment: This indeed sounds like a bug.  You should report it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the below steps :

1. Right click a start menu tile / item
2. Select "Open file location"
3. This will open the Windows Explore with list of all the shortcuts
4. You may then rename the shortcuts as you like.